# Relation between Limit Superior and Supremum implies maximum element

Tags: calculus, upper-lower-bounds

This question is from Spivak,

**19** If A is a bounded infinite set prove

**c)**
If $\limsup A < \sup A$, then A contains a largest element.

**d)**
The analogues for $\liminf A$.

**What I did**

I was able to do the previous items where one shows that $\liminf A \leq \limsup A$ and $\limsup A \leq \sup A$, but I was not able to go any further. I also know that if the equality doesn't hold, then $\sup A> \inf B$ where B is the set of all *almost upper bounds*.

Comment: What is the limsup of a set? I only know what it means in the context of sequences and functions.

Comment: From what I understood, the $\limsup$ of a set is the infimum of the set's endpoint. In math, given a bounded infinite set A, let B be the set of almost upper limits of A, then $\limsup A=\inf B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $B$ is the set of almost upper bounds on $A$, and suppose
$$\inf B < \sup A.$$
Then, there must exist some $b \in B$ such that
$$\inf B \le b < \sup A,$$
as otherwise $\sup A$ would be a lower bound for $B$, which would contradict the above statement.

Since $b \in B$, it follows that $A \cap [b, \infty)$ is finite, and hence has a maximum element $a$. I claim that $a$ is the maximum of $A$. Suppose this is not the case. Then some $a^* > a$ exists in $A$, and since $a \ge b$, we therefore have $a^* \ge b$. Therefore $a^* \in A \cap [b, \infty)$, which contradicts $a$ being the maximum on $A \cap [b, \infty)$. By contradiction, $a$ is the maximum of $A$.

Comment: Thank you for your help!